# How do I set up a Navigation Property in my Code First between a Table and View?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have a simple context that contains 1 Table from a DB and 1 View from the same DB.  The Table has a field, OrderNumber, that is the PK of the View.  The View simply has details that I want to include and as such is a 1:1 with the table.
I am trying to do all of this through Code First and have my Models but I am struggling on how I link them in my Model and have it save just the PK of the View in the OrderNumber field.

Below is what I have so far:

```
public partial class MyTable
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string OrderNumber{ get; set; }   


    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string RequestorNote { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string WashNote { get; set; }

    public StatusChoices Status { get; set; }
}


[Table("MyView")]
public partial class MyView
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string No_ { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Column("Routing No_", Order = 3)]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Routing_No_ { get; set; }

    [Column("Starting Date-Time", Order = 4)]
    public DateTime Starting_Date_Time { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a navigation property like `public virtual ICollection<MyView> Orders { get; set; }` in your table?

Comment: I just want a 1:1 but I believe your point is valid.  I think I want `public virtual MyView Orders { get; set; }`

Comment: Yes, sorry I overlooked your 1:1 requirement. If that ends up working for you let me know and I'll repost my comment as an answer.

Comment: It did, thanks.  I now have a strange CRAZY slow issue but that probably belongs in a separate post.

Comment: I'd do a SQL profile/trace to see what it's doing behind the scenes if possible. Could be a database performance issue, or it could be querying way more data than you really need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `No_` in `MyView` is the `OrderNumber` from `MyTable` why not add a navigation property?

```
public virtual MyView OrderDetails { get; set; }
```